# How to redirect to Index from another controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking through trying to find some way to redirect to an `Index` view from another controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{                
     ApplicationController viewModel = new ApplicationController();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", viewModel);
}
```

This is what I tried right now. Now the code I was given to has a `ActionLink` that links to the page I need to `Redirect` too.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Bally Applications","../Application")
```

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Use the overloads that take the controller name too...

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name","Index", "MyController", null, null)
```

Comment: Ok this worked. I tried this earlier must of been a typo when I did it before.

Comment: did that would of sooner but there was a timer stopping me

Comment: Ahh, for us MVC newbies this was extremely helpful. Just simply redirecting to another view in a different folder represented by a different controller was getting by me until I read this.

Comment: how to redirect to a view without a controller? such as `Shared/Error`

Answer (score 35):

try:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return RedirectToAction("actionName");
    // or
    return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
    // or
    return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", new {/* routeValues, for example: */ id = 5 });
}
```

and in `.cshtml` view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText","actionName")
```

**OR:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText","actionName","controllerName")
```

**OR:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", "controllerName", 
    new { /* routeValues forexample: id = 6 or leave blank or use null */ }, 
    new { /* htmlAttributes forexample: @class = "my-class" or leave blank or use null */ })
```

**Notice** using `null` in final expression is not recommended, and is better to use a blank `new {}` instead of `null`

Comment: In regard to your notice, for what reason is it better to use `new {}` instead of `null`?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the following code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

See [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594.aspx)

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. It gave me page could not be found error

Comment: should be with "Controller": 
`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

Comment: I need to use "/Index" otherwise not found

Comment: @code4j how have you defined your default routes? Have you added default values for controller and action?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the overloads method `RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName);`

**Example:**

```
RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use local redirect.
Following codes are jumping the HomeController's Index page:

```
public class SharedController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult _Layout(string btnLogout)
        {
            if (btnLogout != null)
            {
                return LocalRedirect("~/Index");
            }

            return View();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Complete answer (.Net Core 3.1)

Most answers here are correct but taken a bit out of context, so I will provide a full-fledged answer which works for Asp.Net Core 3.1. For completeness' sake:

```cs
[Route("health")]
[ApiController]
public class HealthController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("some_health_url")]
    public ActionResult SomeHealthMethod() {}
}

[Route("v2")]
[ApiController]
public class V2Controller : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("some_url")]
    public ActionResult SomeV2Method()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SomeHealthMethod", "Health"); // omit "Controller"
    }
}
```

If you try to use any of the url-specific strings, e.g. `"some_health_url"`, it will not work!

Answer (score 0):

Tag helpers:

```
<a asp-controller="OtherController" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary"> Back to Other Controller View </a>
```

In the controller.cs have a method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Titles";
    return View(await Your_Model or Service method);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RedirectToRoute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is another option. Just pass the route as the argument. Also, using nameof() might be a better convention since you are not hard coding the controller name as a string.

```
 return RedirectToRoute(nameof(HomeController) + nameof(HomeController.Index));
```