# Redirect to Action in another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, redirecttoaction

I have two controllers, both called `AccountController`.  One of them, lets call it `Controller A`, is in an `Area` called `Admin` and the other, lets call it `Controller B`, is not in any `Area` (I guess that means it's in the default `Area`?).  `Controller B` has an `action method` called `Login`.  I have an `action method` in `Controller A`, which has this line

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
```

The problem is that I get a `404` when this line gets executed because an attempt is made to redirect to a non-existent `action` in `Controller A`.  I want to call the `action method` in `Controller B`.  Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC Redirect to Index from another Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/mvc-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller)

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You can supply the `area` in the `routeValues` parameter. Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "Admin" });
```

Or

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "" });
```

depending on which area you're aiming for.

Comment: what if I want to go from a view in a certain area to action of a controller which is not in any area. Like in MVC5, the LogOff button on top right is in AccountController, which donot reside in any area. And I want to LogOff from a view in a certain area???

Comment: My second example, `area = ""`, will do that for you.

Comment: This worked for me with ASP.NET Core.... When I upgraded to the latest version the RedirectToAction broke and I got it to work using the area = "" with an empty string.

Answer (score 33):

Use this:

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "" });
```

This will redirect to the `LogIn` action in the `Account` controller in the "global" area.

It's using this `RedirectToAction` overload:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues
)
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", new { area = "Admin" });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
    return this.RedirectToAction<AccountController>(m => m.LogIn());
```

Comment: I like the concept. I have always hated the string part of RedirectToAction and thought it should be more like what you entered, but this appears to anger c#. 

Is this in frameworks newer then 4.6.2?

Comment: @user3071434 No,
you can use with adding "using Microsoft.Web.Mvc".

you can avoid string part and reduce to getting an error on runtime due to the wrong Action text

Comment: This seems to be sadly missing in .NET 6.0 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching them:

```
return RedirectToAction("Account", "Login");
```

I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[RedirectToRoute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is also available. Also, a better way to do it might be using nameof() so you can avoid hardcoding strings in your codebase.

```
return RedirectToRoute(nameof(AccountController) + nameof(AccountController.Login));
```

And, if you are redirecting to an endpoint that takes parameters, pass those along.

```
return RedirectToRoute(nameof(Account) + nameof(Account.ChangePassword), new { id = id });
```

Comment: I notice a caveat using this approach is that you would creating a new request that will pipe down through Routing engine and then reach the controller. If you are making several indirections, response may come out slower compared to RedirectToAction

Answer (score 0):

protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
string actionName,
string controllerName,
Object routeValues
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).