# Weird behaviour with RedirectToAction in .NET Core MVC 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 projects in the same solution. When trying to change on successful login redirect page, I tried redirectToAction. (Just to be clear the code below works for 1 project but not another)

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    //return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerName");
 }
```

So this is the links of the login and the redirected link

https://localhost:44343/Identity/Account/Login

https://localhost:44343/ControllerName

However, when doing the exact same thing in another project it does not seem to work. It baffles me because as far as I know, the project configurations are the same.

https://localhost:44343/Identity/Account/Login

https://localhost:44343/Identity/ControllerName

Edit: This is the issue.^ It is referencing a non-existent page. Somehow it works fine in 1 project but I have to add an extra area parameter in the 2nd project for it to work.

Eventually after some digging and referencing this 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785245/redirect-to-action-in-another-controller/10785274), I modified the code to include new area.

```
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    //return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Competitions", new { area = "" });
}
```

Can some kind soul please explain why this is happening? Thank you very much!

RouteConfig in Project 1:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

RouteConfig in Project 2:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areaRoute",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: You did not specified what the problem actually happening or what error message is it showing?

Comment: This is the problem. It is searching for non-existent page
https://localhost:44343/Identity/ControllerName

Comment: Nothing wrong withing the code you shared! may be any external thing playing a role here! Share you route configuration please!

Comment: Show your area `AreaRegistration` and `RouteConfig` to understand what is happening...

Comment: Edited with RouteConfig details. Seems like there is some difference. Is that why it is affecting?

Comment: Still Nothing wrong within the code you shared!

Comment: Just investigated. That extra routing information, together with areas not provided is indeed causing the issue