# Redirect To Another Post Method on failure of one in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version, redirecttoaction

I am having a **post method A()** in **HomeController** in **controllers folder**, when the method fails or throws some exception, I want to redirect to **another post method A()** which is in **HomeController** **in Customer area**, there are many customer with name eg. FirstCustomer, SecondCustomer,
For first method I am using attribute routing and route is /{customerName}/Home/A?id="xyz"
and using conventional routing for the another A method for which the route is /FirstCustomer/Home/A
I am using .net  framework 4.6.1

I have tried **return RedirectToAction("A", "Home", new {area = "FirstCustomer"})**

but the **RedirectToAction() is making the request get**, so I am getting notfound error in browser console.

is there any work around for redirecting to another post method from one post method.

Comment: same question is here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785245/redirect-to-action-in-another-controller)

Comment: Hi @debug_dk, thanks for the suggestion, but in the reference you provided , there it is redirecting to HttpGet method, and in my case I want to redirect to HttpPost method.
In my research till now, I have found that there is no any direct way of redirecting to any HttpPost method.
also, the RedirectToAction() method makes the request of type GET and not POST.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.