# Return view inside partial to full view on error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have a wizard that loads up a partial view on each step.  When the form generates an error it loads the error page.  However it loads the FULL error page in the partial view and makes it look like its loading two pages at once.  How can I redirect to the error page outside of the partial view?

I have this on the bottom of the step

```
            try
            {
                return PartialView("AccountSelection", vm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        return PartialView();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/mvc-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller ?

Comment: redirect to the error page

Comment: Do you have layout on your error page? share code for the error page also

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd handle errors at a higher level.  You can specify an error page in your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="error.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If the goal is to have just a section of the page show an error message, then you could create a partial page named "Error" and save it in Views/Shared.  Then change your code to...

```
        try
        {
            return PartialView("AccountSelection", vm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return PartialView("Error");
        }
    }
    return PartialView();
```

Comment: I do have it configured in my web.config but for some reason the error generates inside the partialview.  It doesn't redirect to the other page.  It's a null error.

Comment: It's in how you're calling it. What's the line of code that is calling this controller method?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectToAction("ErrorAction","ErroController")`. Based upon your needs, the action might be in a separate controller or in the same one(which I don't think would be right). You'll also need to customize your Error action method and view so that you can pass different messages for different circumstances.