# form submit twice when dropzone integrated in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone in a form. The form already contains fields. When user submits the form, the action (in my case the controller) pointed to the form is called twice: the first with the dropzone files and one second time without the files, why? How can I prevent to re-post the same form the second time?

Here is what I've did:

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "dropzone", id = "myForm" }))
{
... some fields...
<div class="fallback">
                    <!-- this is the fallback if JS isn't working -->
                    <input name="files" type="file" multiple />
                </div>
... submit button ...
}
```

JS:

```
// autodiscover at false otherwise, dropzone will attach twice
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myForm', {
            paramName: 'files',
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 25,
            maxFiles: 25
        });

        $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
        });
```

Thanks to read and maybe help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) This ensures the form is submitted only once.

```
$("form").one("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    window.location.href = "Index.aspx"; //Specify the file name and path
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Pugazh, but I still have two calls to my controller :-/

Comment: thanks again. Now, it submits the form once, files are send to server, but there is no redirection. I've put a ASP.NET RedirectToAction("Index"), but no effect, the form still there...

Comment: @clement : You can use `window.location.href` to redirect the page

Comment: good try :-) but this is dirty workaround... I have to make the redirection in the controller

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/mvc-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller

Comment: Thanks but I use return RedirectToAction("Index");, I'm on the same controller but thanks again :-)