# .Net Switch Views from Controller

Tags: .net, view, controller

I'm trying to switch views from a controller after checking the login info. How can I properly switch to the correct view after running this logic? Or do I need to call the controller which renders the view?

I want to switch to the question explanation view. My existing code is below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult LoginBody(LoginModel info)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(info.Email);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(info.Password);

        //Some login Verification Logic

       return View("~\\Views\\QuestionExplanation\\QuestionExplanation");        
    }
```

My folders are organized as follows:

[image]

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki sorry, what? This doesn't work

Comment: okay this works in my system

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki do you switch to the view or the controller which returns the view?

Comment: Have you tried to perform a `RedirectToAction`, providing the action and controller names? `return RedirectToAction("QuestionExplanation", "QuestionExplanation");` (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892126/177416)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
return RedirectToAction("QuestionExplanation", "QuestionExplanation");
```

You're redirecting to an action, so you can't pass the path to the other view; you need to do it properly.