# Best Practice for redirecting to current page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a method in controller that changes the role of a user. After completion, I am trying to keep the user in the current URL after method in Controller completes. I am currently doing this by sending `return Redirect("/Profile/Index/" + id);`, which is the page I am performing this method from.

This works just fine, but I was wondering if this is best practice, or whether a method exists to simply keep the user within the page.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<form method="POST" asp-area="" asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="Demote" asp-route-id="@Model.UserId">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger fs-5 mt-3">Demote User</button>
</form>
```

**ProfileController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Promote(string id)
{
   var user = _nemesysRepository.GetUserById(id);
   _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, _userManager.GetRolesAsync(_nemesysRepository.GetUserById(id)).Result).Wait();
   _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Investigator");
   return Redirect("/Profile/Index/" + id); //===NEEDS TO REDIRECT TO BACK===
}
```

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/how-to-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller/7892126

Comment: Post-redirect-get is the way to go, to prevent the ugly and confusing "confirm form resubmit" question if the user happens to refresh the resulting page.  See https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/#what-is-prg- for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use the built-in [`RedirectToAction()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L473) method that is more suitable for such scenarios:

```
return RedirectToAction(null, new { id });
```

By passing only the new `routeValues`, the current `action` and `controller` are being automatically preserved.

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttoactionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware `RedirectToAction` allows the passing of `routeValues`.

Answer (score -2):

simply return View(); will return the same current page.

Comment: No, it sends to Promote, which doesn't exist.