# What's wrong with these redirects in .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, .net-6.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this controller/action:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PageController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAsync()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have tried to redirect to it from another controller/action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Entry()
{
    return RedirectToAction("GetAsync","PageController");
}
```

and this:

```
RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "PageController", action = "GetAsync" });
```

Both methods throw an InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

I have tried the "Page" / "api/Page" / "api/PageController" variants..

What am I missing? This should be SO easy?

Thanks..

**EDIT:**

`return Redirect("api/Page");` does the job, but I would really like to see an example of correct usage of RedirectToAction / RedirectToRoute in the mentioned context.

Comment: It *is* easy. Your URL is `api/Page`, not `api/PageController/GetAsync`. The action `GetAsync` handles the HTTP GET request on the controller's route. If your Web API [uses Swagger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0) you'll be able to see routes and actions in a web page and even test them. Adding Swagger (assuming it wasn't added by a template) [requires only a couple of lines of config code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah.. But I still can't get it working. How do I implement your comment in code. Could you show me the redirect code oneliner that solves my problem ;)

Comment: This [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/how-to-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller) will help. The actual action should be `Index` and no, that's not an MVC quirk. When the first web servers were created `index.html` was the default page, so `Index` became the default everywhere.  `Get` is actually a shortcut for `GetIndex`. The web app project templates use `Index` as a default when an action name is missing.  Try `RedirectToAction("Index","Page")` or `RedirectToAction("Index","PageController")`

Comment: Also check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892094/how-to-redirect-to-index-from-another-controller]. As the examples show, the route defaults mean that `Home/Index` and `Home` both call the same action

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's exactly the examples I have been trying to implement with no luck.